# How to retrieve a single month for mutiple dates belonging to a month using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting dates like 24/5/2011, 25/5/2011,26/5/2011 from MySQL database.

How to get a single month using date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d",$date) in PHP, so that it does not display 5,5,5 but a single 5 for all the dates of the month?

Comment: What about `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
date( 'm', strtotime( $date ));
```

That will return just the month.  `strtotime()` parses `$date` into a timestamp, then `date()` formats it according to the specified format.

Additionally, you mentioned you were pulling this from MySQL.  If your query looks like this:

```
SELECT date FROM table;
```

You could return just the month in the query by changing it:

```
SELECT MONTH( date ) AS month FROM table;
```

That way PHP would just get the the month, and you wouldn't have to recursively apply formatting to the data returned from the database.

Comment: if i have got a month as 5, how to get it as a string in php

Comment: @akshara, `date( 'm', strtotime( $date ));` will do it.. it would just return "5".